# Реализация справочника

Tags: xml, xslt

Как реализовать справочник через xslt-преобразование.  Я вывел все значения справочника из блока /price. Осталось сопоставить каждому значению заголовок из блока /reference. Как это сделать, я не понимаю.

Объясните, пожалуйста, основную идею.

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1:**
Прописать заголовки прямо в преобразовании. Мне кажется это будет целесообразно, поскольку поля (percent, quantity и т.д.) у вас там жёстко зашиты.

```
<ul class="price_desc">             
    <li class="per">
        Процентное содержание жира:<xsl:value-of select="percent" />
    </li>

    <li>
        Вес куска:<xsl:value-of  select="weight"/>
    </li>

    <li>
        Цвет:<xsl:value-of  select="color"/>
    </li>

    <li>
        цена:<xsl:value-of  select="price"/>
    </li>

    <li>
        Количество:<xsl:value-of  select="quantity"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Вариант 2:**
Выводить поля и заголовки динамически. Основная идея - с помощью функции `concat()` вычисляем имя необходимого узла с заголовком:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
    <article class="price_unit">
        <div class="price_img">
            <img src="{image}" alt="" width="180" height="200" />
        </div>

        <h1>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="header"/>
        </h1>

        <ul class="price_desc"> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name() != 'image'][name() != 'header']"/>
        </ul>
    </article>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item/*[name() != 'image'][name() != 'header']">
  <li>
      <xsl:variable name="tagname">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), '_2')"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of  select="//reference/*[name() = $tagname]"/> <xsl:value-of select="."/>      
  </li>
</xsl:template>
```